# centering longtable and changing distance between lines

Tags: longtable

This is my code :

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}[c]{|m{0.3\linewidth}|m{0.7\linewidth} |}  
   \hline      \textbf{Symbol} &  \textbf{Definition}
        \\\hline       \endfirsthead 
        \hline     
%   \textbf{Symbol} &  \textbf{Definition}
    %   \\\hline   
    %   \endhead   
$X$    & Unwatermarked dataset   \\

$X^{\prime}$                 & A watermarked dataset                                                                     \\
$\overline{X}$                              & The mean of the dataset $X$                                                               \\
$\overline{X^{\prime}}$                     & The mean of the dataset $X^{\prime}$                                                      \\
$G$                                         & Pseudorandom number generator                                                             \\
$K$                                         & The watermark                                                                             \\
$n$                                         & The length of the dataset, and the watermark sequence                                     \\
$SH_{key}$                                  & A secret key used to shuffle the data                                                     \\
$S$                                         & The sequence generated via the pseudorandom number generator                              \\
$\hat{X}$                                   & A copy of the data expected to be watermarked                                             \\
$S_{X}^{2}$                                 & Variance for the dataset $X$                                                              \\
$S_{X^{\prime}}^{2}$                        & Variance for the dataset $X^{\prime}$                                                     \\
$s_{i}$                                     & Individual element in the sequence $S$ at the position $i$                                \\
$P$                                    & The probability for a variable                                                            \\
$T$                                         & Sequence follows a Gaussian $N(0,1)$ distribution                                         \\
$t_{i}$                                     & Individual element in the sequence $T$ at the position $i$                                \\
$M$                                         & A secret value kept with the watermarker in the watermarking algorithm 2                  \\
$\epsilon$                                  & Determines the error in the results of the watermarked dataset $X^{\prime}$               \\
a, b, $\lambda$                             & Parameters used to watermark the dataset $X$ using the watermarking algorithm 2           \\
$x_{i}$                                     & Individual element in the sequence $X$ at the position $i$                                \\
$x_{i}^{\prime}$                            & Individual element in the sequence $X'$ at the position $i$                               \\
$\left|t_{i}\right|$                        & Absolute value of $t_{i}$                                                                 \\
$\hat{M}$                                   & The verified secret value in the watermarked data $\hat{X}$                               \\
$E(.)$                                      & Encryption function                                                                       \\
%$\mathcal{O}$                               & Time complexity                                                                           \\
$\overline{n}$                              & Represents the RLWE dimension                                                             \\
$q$                                         & The ciphertext modulus                                                                    \\
$X^{\prime\prime}$                          & Watermarked and obfuscated dataset                                                        \\
$Obf_{key}$                                 & Secret key used to obfuscate and deobfuscate data                                         \\
$\hat{x}_{i}$                               & Individual element in the sequence $\hat{X}$ at the position $i$                          \\
$C$                                         & A column of data                                                                          \\%delete it? because it conflicts with...
$r$                                         & The number of ones in a binary sequence                                                   \\
$Bob_{RK}$                                  & Bob's repacking key                                                                       \\
$Bob_{SwK}$                                 & Bob's key for the key-switch function                                                     \\
$Bob_{pk}$                                  & Bob's public key                                                                          \\
$Bob_{EK}$                                  & Bob's evaluation key                                                                      \\
$Bob_{RotK}$                                & Bob's rotation key                                                                        \\
$Bob_{RelK}$                                & Bob's relinearization key                                                                 \\
$Bob_{s}$                                   & Bob's secret key                                                                          \\
$\textbf{g}_{digit}$                        & The digit decomposition gadget                                                            \\
$\textbf{g}_{rns}$                          & The RNS decomposition gadget                                                              \\
$\Delta$                                    & The scaling factor                                                                        \\
$\underline{n}$                             & Represents the LWE dimension for the input into the look-up table                         \\
$n^\prime$                                  & Represents the LWE dimension for the output of the look-up table                          \\
$\Delta$                                    & The scaling factor                                                                        \\
$B_{ks}$                                    & The digit decomposition base                                                              \\
$h$                                         & The hamming weight                                                                        \\
$msg$                                       & Indicates the message interval that the look-up table can process                         \\
$S2C$                                       & Slot to coefficient function                                                              \\
$moduli$                                    & Represents the multiplicative depth for a ciphertext                                      \\
$\mu$s                                      & Microseconds                                                                              \\\hline
  \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that it's  not centered in the second page and the distance between lines is small ! Any help is highly appreciated !

Comment: Could you post a  *complete* compilable code. We do'nt even know what your document class is.

Comment: I have edited my post ! Thanks in advance

Comment: `|m{0.3\linewidth}|m{0.7\linewidth} |` is too wide, you have `\linewidith+4\tabcolsep+3\arrayrulewidth`

Comment: unrelated but `$X^{\prime}$ ` is normally written as `$X'$ ` (same output, but simpler input)

Answer (score 1):

Your table is not centred because  you didn't take into account
the  value of `\tabcolsep` and  thus it was too wide to fit the line width. I reduced a bit the first column width, and now it is centred. As to the spacing between rows, the `cellspace` package lets you define minimal vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier  prefixed with letter `S` by default (or `C` if you load `siunitx`, or any letter you please with a loading time option). Hope this code provides a result more like you want:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,twoside]{report}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{cellspace}
    \setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{6pt}
    \setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{6pt}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \begin{document}
     \lipsum[11]
        \begin{longtable}[c]{|S{m{0.2\linewidth}}|S{m{0.7\linewidth}} |}
       \hline \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Definition}
            \\\hline \endfirsthead
            \hline
    $X$ & Unwatermarked dataset \\

    $X^{\prime}$ & A watermarked dataset \\
    $\overline{X}$ & The mean of the dataset $X$ \\
    $\overline{X^{\prime}}$ & The mean of the dataset $X^{\prime}$ \\
    $G$ & Pseudorandom number generator \\
    $K$ & The watermark \\
    $n$ & The length of the dataset, and the watermark sequence \\
    $SH_{key}$ & A secret key used to shuffle the data \\
    $S$ & The sequence generated via the pseudorandom number generator \\
    $\hat{X}$ & A copy of the data expected to be watermarked \\
    $S_{X}^{2}$ & Variance for the dataset $X$ \\
    $S_{X^{\prime}}^{2}$ & Variance for the dataset $X^{\prime}$ \\
    $s_{i}$ & Individual element in the sequence $S$ at the position $i$ \\
    $P$ & The probability for a variable \\
    $T$ & Sequence follows a Gaussian $N(0,1)$ distribution \\
    $t_{i}$ & Individual element in the sequence $T$ at the position $i$ \\
    $M$ & A secret value kept with the watermarker in the watermarking algorithm 2 \\
    $\epsilon$ & Determines the error in the results of the watermarked dataset $X^{\prime}$ \\
    a, b, $\lambda$ & Parameters used to watermark the dataset $X$ using the watermarking algorithm 2 \\
    $x_{i}$ & Individual element in the sequence $X$ at the position $i$ \\
    $x_{i}^{\prime}$ & Individual element in the sequence $X'$ at the position $i$ \\
    $\left|t_{i}\right|$ & Absolute value of $t_{i}$ \\
    $\hat{M}$ & The verified secret value in the watermarked data $\hat{X}$ \\
    $E(.)$ & Encryption function \\
    %$\mathcal{O}$ & Time complexity \\
    $\overline{n}$ & Represents the RLWE dimension \\
    $q$ & The ciphertext modulus \\
    $X^{\prime\prime}$ & Watermarked and obfuscated dataset \\
    $Obf_{key}$ & Secret key used to obfuscate and deobfuscate data \\
    $\hat{x}_{i}$ & Individual element in the sequence $\hat{X}$ at the position $i$ \\
    $C$ & A column of data \\%delete it? because it conflicts with...
    $r$ & The number of ones in a binary sequence \\
    $Bob_{RK}$ & Bob's repacking key \\
    $Bob_{SwK}$ & Bob's key for the key-switch function \\
    $Bob_{pk}$ & Bob's public key \\
    $Bob_{EK}$ & Bob's evaluation key \\
    $Bob_{RotK}$ & Bob's rotation key \\
    $Bob_{RelK}$ & Bob's relinearization key \\
    $Bob_{s}$ & Bob's secret key \\
    $\textbf{g}_{digit}$ & The digit decomposition gadget \\
    $\textbf{g}_{rns}$ & The RNS decomposition gadget \\
    $\Delta$ & The scaling factor \\
    $\underline{n}$ & Represents the LWE dimension for the input into the look-up table \\
    $n^\prime$ & Represents the LWE dimension for the output of the look-up table \\
    $\Delta$ & The scaling factor \\
    $B_{ks}$ & The digit decomposition base \\
    $h$ & The hamming weight \\
    $msg$ & Indicates the message interval that the look-up table can process \\
    $S2C$ & Slot to coefficient function \\
    $moduli$ & Represents the multiplicative depth for a ciphertext \\
    $\mu$s & Microseconds \\\hline
      \end{longtable}

     \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After one year (I didn't notice this question before ...)

- For table I would use `longtblr` of `tabularray` package with libraries `amsmath`, `booktabs` and `siunitx`.
- Additionally is used `mathtools` package for defining delimiters
- In preamble are defined math operators, which are used at variable labels or names:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{report}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, booktabs, siunitx}
\DeclareMathOperator{\key}{key}
\DeclareMathOperator{\bob}{Bob}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rk}{RK}
\DeclareMathOperator{\swk}{SwK}
\DeclareMathOperator{\pk}{pk}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ek}{ek}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rotk}{RotK}
\DeclareMathOperator{\relk}{RelK}
\DeclareMathOperator{\digit}{digit}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rns}{rns}
\DeclareMathOperator{\s2c}{S2C}
\DeclareMathOperator{\msg}{msg}
\DeclareMathOperator{\moduli}{moduli}
%
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}


\begin{document}
    \lipsum[11]
\begingroup
\DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}{}
\SetTblrStyle{contfoot}{font=\small\sffamily\itshape}
\begin{longtblr}[
    entry=none,     % <---
    label=none  ]
                {vlines,
                 colspec = { Q[l, mode=math] X[l] },
                 row{1}  = {font=\bfseries, mode=text},
                 rowsep  = 1pt,
                 rowhead = 1
                 }
    \toprule
Symbol          &   Definition                          \\
    \midrule
X               & Unwatermarked dataset                 \\
X'              & A watermarked dataset                 \\
\overline{X}    & The mean of the dataset $X$           \\
\overline{X'}   & The mean of the dataset $X'$          \\
G               & Pseudorandom number generator         \\
K               & The watermark                         \\
n               & The length of the dataset, and the watermark sequence         \\
SH_{key}        & A secret key used to shuffle the data                         \\
S               & The sequence generated via the pseudorandom number generator  \\
\hat{X}         & A copy of the data expected to be watermarked                 \\
S_{X}^{2}       & Variance for the dataset $X$          \\
S_{X'}^{2}      & Variance for the dataset $X$          \\
s_{i}           & Individual element in the sequence $S$ at the position $i$    \\
P               & The probability for a variable        \\
T               & Sequence follows a Gaussian $N(0,1)$ distribution             \\
t_{i}           & Individual element in the sequence $T$ at the position $i$    \\
M               & A secret value kept with the watermarker in the watermarking algorithm 2  \\
\epsilon        & Determines the error in the results of the watermarked dataset $X'$       \\
a, b, \lambda   & Parameters used to watermark the dataset $X$ using the watermarking algorithm 2 \\
x_{i}           & Individual element in the sequence $X$ at the position i      \\
x_{i}'  & Individual element in the sequence $X'$ at the position i     \\
\abs{t_{i}}     & Absolute value of $t_{i}$              \\
\hat{M}         & The verified secret value in the watermarked data $\hat{X}$   \\
E(\cdot)        & Encryption function                   \\
%\mathcal{O} & Time complexity \\
\overline{n}    & Represents the RLWE dimension         \\
q               & The ciphertext modulus                \\
X''             & Watermarked and obfuscated dataset    \\
\obf_{\key}      & Secret key used to obfuscate and deobfuscate data                 \\
\widehat{x}_{i} & Individual element in the sequence $\widehat{X}$ at the position $i$  \\
C               & A column of data                      \\
r               & The number of ones in a binary sequence                           \\
\bob_{\rk}      & Bob's repacking key                   \\
\bob_{SwK}      & Bob's key for the key-switch function \\
\bob_{pk}       & Bob's public key                      \\
\bob_{EK}       & Bob's evaluation key                  \\
\bob_{RotK}     & Bob's rotation key                    \\
\bob_{RelK}     & Bob's relinearization key             \\
\bob_{s}        & Bob's secret key                      \\
\mathbf{g}_{\digit} & The digit decomposition gadget    \\
\mathbf{g}_{\rns}   & The RNS decomposition gadget      \\
\Delta          & The scaling factor                    \\
\underline{n}   & Represents the LWE dimension for the input into the look-up table \\
n'              & Represents the LWE dimension for the output of the look-up table  \\
\Delta          & The scaling factor                    \\
B_{ks}          & The digit decomposition base          \\
h               & The hamming weight                    \\
\msg            & Indicates the message interval that the look-up table can process \\
\s2c            & Slot to coefficient function          \\
\moduli         & Represents the multiplicative depth for a ciphertext \\
\unit{\micro\second}    & Microseconds                  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd also be tempted to replace all instances of `^{\prime}` with `'`.

Comment: @Mico, I hardly try (manually ) to do this, but it may happens, that I overlooked some of them, huh, now I find two cases and some other small glitch regarding use of `\hat` . Now I use editor to replace all this. Hopefully now all is  corrected. Thank you very much to pointed me on this.